# Determine article path of a MediaWiki installation

Tags: java, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

How can I reliable determine the article path (`$wgArticlePath`) of a wiki using MediaWiki when I only know the domain of the wiki?

I made some research but only found ways to find that out in own installations, not installation I have no control of.

Methods I came up with so far but doesn't always seem to work:

- Requesting the website of the root domain and going through the links but I don't know which links go to a wiki. In some cases the URL also only links to the subdomain, not the homepage (which would include the article path) so I would also need to request the homepages of each wiki.
- Using `api.php` but I didn't find a way. It also seems as this URL can be modified.
- Using the page `Special:Version` but that would require that I already know the article path. I could only verify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the article path from the API, using `action=query&meta=siteinfo`. The article path is included in a bunch of properties called “general”. An example from English Wikipedia, querying for the `general` properties only:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&meta=siteinfo&siprop=general
```

In this case, you will find: `"articlepath": "/wiki/$1"`

If you do not even know the path to the API, you can parse the markup of the starting page (or any page), and look for a `<link rel="EditURI">` tag in the header. You will find this on any default installation of a fairly recent MediaWiki version (though it would obviously be perfectly possible to remove this tag through the use of some extension).

Comment: The discussion [here](https://github.com/mwclient/mwclient/issues/34) may be of interest.